# Cleaning up after each activity do's and donts

Tags: android, android-activity, optimization, code-cleanup

In my application I have many activities, some of them are finished() when moving to a new activity and some are kept on the stack so i can navigate back.

I now want to make sure I tidy my code in the correct way.

so how do i clean up and where do i do it

Strings (do these need nullifying?) 
ArrayLists (do these need nullifying?)
Library class instances 
custom class instances 
inner class instances (static)

do i always clean up in the onDestroy or onPause() and recreate in the onResume as well as saving instance data when moving from one activity and back again.

Are there any good articles that cover all of this.

Comment: If you are happy with GarbageCollector taking care of it automatically then the answer is no. One thing to keep in mind is you don't want any static content to keep a reference on any of the object in your activity. This is a memory leak, because GC can not clean these resources for you.

Comment: @AndrejJurkin can you explain the static part and give an example as i believe i do have memory leaks

Comment: You should then definitely test it with [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). Say you have some class C and it has some static field for example public static Context context; Inside your activity you call C.context = this; So now your activity is being referenced from the static field, so GC can not do the work and therefore untill you clean up manually your activity can not be GC'd.

Comment: @AndrejJurkin you my friend are a god!  LeakCanary is amazing!